# I want to display my modal box after click into selecting college, how to do this?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i want to display my modal box after clicking into selecting list but at this moment how to do it, can anyone help me please :(

As you can see my pic, after clicking on "please select college" i want to show my "modal box"... i don't want source code for model box...i already coded ..pls check my source but problem is how to show it after clicking "selecting list"?????

[image]

please help how to do it?

here is my source code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Select your college from the list.
    </title>
    <style>
        #img{
            width: 104%;
            z-index: 1;
            height: 355px;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding: 0px;
            margin-top: -9px;
            margin-left: -8px;
            margin-right: -2px;
        }

        .font{
            font-family: "Segoe UI Light";
            float: left;
        }

        *{
            margin: 5;
            padding: 0;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            text-align: center;
        }

        select::-ms-expand{
            display: none;
        }

        body{
            background: #444;
        }

        select{
            width: 50%;
            color: #A0A0A0 ;
            font-size: 1em;
            line-height: 1.2em;
            margin: 0 0 10px;
            padding: 6px 0;
            border: 0 none;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-indent: 0.01px;
            text-overflow: "";
            back-image: none;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
            -moz-appearance: none;
            -ms-appearance: none;
            apperance: none;

        }

        select option{
            background: #444;
        }

        a:link{
            display: block;
            color: #663333;
            background-color: #B80000 ;
            width: 120px;
            text-align: center;
            height: 45px;
            padding: 10px;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: default;
        }

        a:hover{
            background-color: #D80000;
        }

        .float{
            float: right;
            font-family: "Segoe UI Light";
        }

        .modalDialog{
            position: fixed;
            font-family: "Segoe UI Light";
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
            z-index: 99999;
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
            -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
            pointer-events: none;
        }

        .modalDialog:target {
            opacity:1;
            pointer-events: auto;
        }

        .modalDialog > div {
            width: 400px;
            position: relative;
            margin: 10% auto;
            padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            background: #fff;
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
            background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
        }

        .close {
            background: #606061;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            line-height: 25px;
            position: absolute;
            right: -12px;
            text-align: center;
            top: -10px;
            width: 24px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: bold;
            -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
            -moz-border-radius: 12px;
            border-radius: 12px;
            -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
        }

        .close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }

    </style>
    <body>
        <img id="img" src="images/party_girls.jpg" alt="Select_your_college" />

    <h1 class="font"><font color="white">Welcome</font></h1>
       <br><br><br><br>
       <br><br>
        <select>
            <option selected="selected">Please select your college</option>
            <option>Maharishi Arvind International Institute of technology, kota-rajasthan</option>
        </select>

        <a href="#openModal"></a>
        <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
            <div>
                <a href="#close" title="close" class="close">X</a>
                <h2>We are sorry..</h2>
                <p>At this moment, only one college can be selected we are working on others college, if your college is listed then you could join this.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <a href="" class="float">Next</a>
    </body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: If I were you, i'd drop the use of `<br>` for spacing and use CSS `margin` instead. The same goes for `<font>`, you can use CSS for this. This way you'll separate content and style, which makes your pages lighter, better rendered and easier to read (screen readers, bots, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put it before `</body>`

```
<script>
$("option:contains('Please select your college')").click(function(){
$("a[href='#openModal']")[0].click();
});
</script>
```

if you want to open modal immediately after clicking dropdown, not its options, use :

```
<script>
    $("select").click(function(){
    $("a[href='#openModal']")[0].click();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You're missing quotes `$("a[href='#openModal']")[0].click();`

Comment: thank you Tilwin, but it works fine without quotes too for me

Comment: Put it before </body>